# Format usb drive with gdisk gpt partition for WIndows

Tags: linux, windows, gpt

Trying to make GPT partition with gdisk at ubuntu for using at windows

make partiton with gdisk and mkfs.ntfs for ntfs file system

after make NTFS file system set gpt attirubtes

At gdisk
enter Expert command with 'x' and set gpt attribute with '60' (read only) and '0' (system partiton)

I set it to read-only, but on Windows, it shows 'access denied' and I can't access it.

But Format with Diskpart on Windows, and Set attribute on Ubuntu with gdisk, Read only Attribute works

I have to format on ubuntu not on windows

what's the problem?

Comment: Windows on gpt partitioning must be UEFI install. UEFI install of Windows requires multiple partitions, esp (FAT32), system reserved (unformatted before first NTFS partition), main install, and usually several recovery partitions. Best to let Windows create its own partitions in unallocated space.